# Angular request go to error function instead of success

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is controller code:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public string test()
    {
        return "hi there";
    }
```

and here is Angular code:

```
 function testFunction()
    {
        $http.get('http://localhost:1675/api/Product/test').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            alert(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            alert('Error');

        });
    }
```

it access the controller but it goes to `error` function!, when `data` is checked it was found null! it suppose to return `hi there`
anything wrong in this code?

Comment: Looks like your API does not work correctly. Check it, probably using a REST client or curl. Or have a look at the `data` and `error` values in the `error` callback. Most likely, the issue is not on the Angular side.

Comment: I checked that from browser  and it works fine!

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console log for errors?

Comment: after adding `[Route("Product/test")]` it works, may I know why?

Comment: not related to the problem (which appears to be a server side route issue), but this is relevant to your code: [Angular HTTP success/error methods deprecated, removed in Angular 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)

Comment: Above you said, that the URL was working from the browser. It's also unclear what your sever-side technology is. It's very obviously **not** JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding `[Route("Product/test")]` it works.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Product/test")]
    public string test()
    {
        return "hi there";
    }
```